# Amazon SWF to schedule task

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-swf

I am using python boto library to implement SWF.

We are simulating a workflow where we want to execute same task 10 times in a workflow. After the 10th time, the workflow will be marked complete.

The problem is, we want to specify an interval for execution which varies based on the execution count. For example: 5 minutes for 1st execution, 10 minutes for 2nd execution, and so on.

How do I schedule a task by specifying time to execute?

Comment: Write a script which does your work and write a shell script which executes this file on specified time intervals

Comment: I want all the scheduling work to be done within swf, I mean decider should take care of scheduling. We can just write a logic to get next schedule time.

Answer (score 1):

There is no delay option when scheduling an activity. The solution is to schedule a timer with delay based on activity execution count and when the timer fires schedule an activity execution.